# GWT AbstractMethodError(Linker.link): possible factors?

Tags: gwt

First of all, I am sorry for asking such a general question without a lot of details.
If you feel that this cannot be answered, feel free to ask for other details, or just go about your day please. Newbs know when they are asking annoying general questions and don't need to be told that.

My situation is i have been given a GWT project to take ownership on and I don't have access to the authors.

When starting the project in development (hosted) mode I get the following error:

```
Linking module 'com.mymodule'
        Invoking Linker RPC policy file manifest
           [ERROR] Failed to link
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:com.google.gwt.core.ext.Linker.link(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/LinkerContext;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/ArtifactSet;)Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/ArtifactSet;
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.StandardLinkerContext.invokeLink(StandardLinkerContext.java:408)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.link(DevModeBase.java:947)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doSlowStartup(DevMode.java:374)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1057)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:783)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:275)
```

Uninformative, to say the least. I have been trying to figure this out but to no avail.
What are the possible causes to this error and how do I go about determining them?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely there is more than one copy of gwt-dev or gwt-user on the classpath, of different versions. This will be on the classpath that is doing the compilation (or in this case, dev mode), not compilation. Without more info about how you are running, I am assuming you are invoking the DevMode class from the command line, and somehow are building up a classpath that is inconsistent.

To make the question clearer, perhaps add details about how you are running dev mode, what the classpath looks like in that situation, and whether or not compilation works (and if that works, how is the classpath different there).

Comment: Thanks, I am running it from eclipse by doing 'Run As->Web Application'. Compilation succeeds if I run the build script or use eclipse to 'GWT Compile' the project. I do however have an issue with 2 GWT SDKs configured in eclipse since I installed the latest SDK and this project comes with an older SDK. So I installed an older SDK (2.0.3) and changed the project properties to use that one. When I look at the 'Java Build Path' I can see only one GWT-dev and GWT-user. I will try to rebuild the project with the new SDK and see if there are classpath issues.